# How do I Update the only field that is being chosen by the user from Dropdown List in my stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, ado.net

I have stored Procedure, that i am using in ADO.NET code. When the user selects some value from dropdown, it should update only that value and not pass null values in other columns. I am not able to implement this logic.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateEmployeeField]
(
@id INTEGER,
@first_name VARCHAR(10),  
@last_name VARCHAR(10),  
@salary DECIMAL(10,2),  
@city VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
    UPDATE [EMPLOYEE] SET [first_name] =COALESCE(first_name,@first_name),
                          [last_name] =COALESCE(last_name,@last_name), 
                          [salary]=COALESCE(salary,@salary),
                          [city]=COALESCE(city,@city)
                          WHERE [id] =@id
```

Corresponding ADO.NET code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateEmployeeField", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",TextBox7.Text);
                    if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "first_name")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBox8.Text);
                    }

                    if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "last_name")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBox8.Text);
                    }

                    if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "salary")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", TextBox8.Text);
                    }

                    if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "city")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox8.Text);
                    }

                    con.Open();
                    int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (count != 0)
                        Label2.Text = "Information Updated";
                    else
                        Label2.Text = "Information not updated";
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
                catch (SqlException exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `coalesce()`s are backwards:

```
UPDATE [EMPLOYEE]
    SET [first_name] = COALESCE(@first_name, first_name),
        [last_name] = COALESCE(@last_name, last_name), 
        [salary] = COALESCE(@salary, salary),
        [city] = COALESCE(@city, city)
    WHERE [id] = @id;
```

Your version only changes the column names when the *column values* are `NULL`.  This version changes the value to the new value when the new value *is not `NULL`*.

Comment: I did not get you.Sorry for being dumb.